# Height of recursion tree vs the levels

Tags: algorithm

I read that the height of tree is lgn for base=2 and number of levels are lgn+1. What's the difference b/w both? Aren't they including top most level in the height calculation or the base cases? Can someone please prove me this with some practical example using more grammar instead of Mathematical equations?

Comment: where did you read this? context matters. references plz.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Introduction to Algorithm 3rd edition by Cormen. It's from the third 4th chapter( Divide & Conquer)

Answer (score 1):

First, the height of a *balanced* tree is O(lg n); a completely unbalanced tree (such as a linked list) has height O(n).

The height of a node is its distance from the root (and thus the height of a tree is the maximum distance of *any* node from the root). From this definition, you can see that the height of the root is 0, its children have height 1, *their* children have height 2, and so on. A level can be considered all nodes with the same height.

Now consider the set of levels in a tree. The only way to have 0 levels is to have an empty tree; as soon as you have even a single node, there will be at least one level, the one containing the root node with height 0. That is, there is a differene between *labelling* levels and *counting* levels. Level 1 is the node with height 0; level 2 is the set of nodes with height 1, level i is the set of nodes with height i-1, until you get to level lg n + 1 consisting of nodes with height lg n.